# Output comma with get_field in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I would like to output the name and the degree in this format: John Doe, PhD

My code is as follows:

```
$degree = get_field( 'degree', $post->ID );
<h4 class="block-slider-faculty__slide__details__title"><?php the_title(); ?><?php echo implode(', ', $degree); ?></h4>
```

I got a "Warning: Implode(): invalid arguments passed in…" error.

I believe I need to put the `$degree` in an array? Please let me know how I can do that with the code above. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`implode()` is intended to take an array and convert it to a string.  Unless the value of `$degree` is an array, you're going to get an error.

If `$degree` is already a string value, there's no need to `implode()` it.

I'm guessing here because you didn't include any information in your question about where the name comes from and if the "degree" field is simply the degree. So the following is based on an assumption that `the_title()` is the name and `$degree` simply contains the degree as a string (such as "PhD").

`$degree = get_field( 'degree', $post->ID );
<h4 class="block-slider-faculty__slide__details__title"><?php the_title(); ?>, <?php echo $degree; ?></h4>`

Of course, if there is a possibility that `$degree` is empty, you'd have to also account for that, so the following might be better in that regard:

`$degree = get_field( 'degree', $post->ID );
$degree_output = ( $degree ) ? ", " . $degree : '';
<h4 class="block-slider-faculty__slide__details__title"><?php the_title(); echo $degree_output; ?></h4>`

(Also note above, there's no need in the second example (nor your original) to close PHP and then reopen it right away.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code works perfectly. I really appreciate it.